# Swipe gesture for UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a feeling the answer is going to be "you can't do that", but hope springs eternal!

One scene in my app is a UITableView; the table represents a month and each row is a day of the month.  I have a small UIView at the top of the table with a "Prev" and 'Next" button.  Selecting next results in the table displaying the next month and Prev causes the prior month to be displayed.  All of this works fine.

What I would like to do is add left & right gesture recognizers to move from month to month, performing the same function as the Prev and Next buttons.  Please note I don't need anything to happen to/with the UITableViewCell.

When I searched for this on the web, the overwhelming number of posts seems to be how to handle gesture recognizers in a UITableViewCell. This is not helpful in my case.

I am using Objective-C and Xcode 11.3.1.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it. By disabling the interaction of each cell you should be able to pass a 'UIGestureRecognizer' to the tableView.

Here is a short example. Sorry I used Swift but you can probably get the gist of it.

After adding the tableView I Added these gestureRecognizers to it.

```
let leftGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(leftSwiped))
    leftGesture.direction = .left
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(leftGesture)

    let rightGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(rightSwiped))
    rightGesture.direction = .right
    tableView.addGestureRecognizer(rightGesture)
```

Each one calls the following functions:

```
@objc func leftSwiped() {
    print("LEFT")
}

@objc func rightSwiped() {
    print("Right")
}
```

and in cell for row I just disabled the user interaction of the cell:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")!
    cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    cell.backgroundColor = .random()
    return cell
}
```

When I tried it, swiping right and left on the table view would print appropriately in the logger.

Hope this helps,
Alan

Comment: Alan - thanks but there this is still not working for me.  To test I made a simple application and added the gesture recognizers from the storyboard have a single cell in the table and the actions to not fire when i swipe left/right.  Same simple app, with a UIView and gesture recognizers and swipes work perfectly.  I want to get this working, but disabling the user interaction will be a problem in my app.  When my app shows the current month, rows for days after today already have user interaction disabled.  But i need to be able to select the other rows to switch to the day view.

Comment: i need to explore more; i found that gesture recognizers work on a different UITableView in my app but not the one in my question.

Comment: In the example I set I added the gestures programmatically and it was working. If what i did helped could you at least throw me an upvote?

Comment: Alan -  I did give you an upvote1  Unfortunately I was too new of a SO user to have upvotes visible publicly.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer in Objective C

same answer like @Alan but just no need to add below line in `cellForRowAt` method

```
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
cell.backgroundColor = .random()
```

Use below method for swipe gesture in TableView

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
 {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *leftGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeLeftHandler)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer: leftGestureRecognizer];

    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightGestureRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeRightHandler)];
    [self.tableView addGestureRecognizer: leftGestureRecognizer];

}

-(void) swipeLeftHandler
{
    NSLog(@"SWIPE Left");
// add same method which you call on next button’s click
}


-(void) swipeRightHandler{
    NSLog(@"SWIPE Right");
// add same method which you call on previous button’s click

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is fixed.

I found that the recognizer worked as I expected if I added the swipe recognizer to my tableview programmatically.  But if use the storyboard to add the swipe recognizers, they did not work at all.  This is what i was testing when I posted my question.

After digging a bit, I found that the storyboard recognizers needed to be added to the reference outlet collections in my tableview.  For whatever reason this did not happen when I added them originally.  Once I connected the recognizers to my tableview, everything worked exactly as intended.